# Showing that the Cycloid is an injective curve

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, multivariable-calculus

I want to prove that $f(t)=(t-\sin(t),1-\cos(t))$ is an injective function.

My first attempt is to do something like this:

$t-\sin(t)=s-\sin(s)$, $1-\cos(t)=1-\cos(s)$ which takes the form

$$t-\sin(t)=s-\sin(s) \\
\cos(t)=\cos(s)$$

and I stop there because I didn't find a good way to finish this system. Any hint? Thanks!

Comment: Hint: it turns out that $t \mapsto t - \sin t$ is injective. This is because $|\sin a - \sin b| < |a - b|$ whenever $a \neq b$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In particular, the map $t \mapsto t - \sin t$ is injective.

For consider the fact that $\sin a - \sin b = \sin (\frac{a + b}{2} + \frac{a - b}{2}) - \sin (\frac{a + b}{2} - \frac{a - b}{2}) = 2\cos \frac{a + b}{2} \sin \frac{a - b}{2}$.

Suppose that $a \neq b$. Then we have $|\sin a - \sin b| = |2\cos \frac{a + b}{2} \sin \frac{a - b}{2}| \leq 2 |\sin \frac{a - b}{2}| < 2 |\frac{a - b}{2}| = |a - b|$.

Then we see that $|(a - \sin a) - (b - \sin b)| = |a - b + \sin a - \sin b| > |a - b| - |\sin a - \sin b| > 0$.

Therefore, if $a \neq b$ then $a - \sin a \neq b - \sin b$. This demonstrates that the map $t \mapsto t - \sin t$ is injective.

Edit: perhaps a simpler proof is

$(a - \sin a) - (b - \sin b) = \int\limits_b^a (1 - \cos t) dt$

Now $1 - \cos t$ is always nonnegative. And if $a > b$, then $1 - \cos t$ will be positive at some point on the interval $(a, b)$. Therefore, $(a - \sin a) - (b - \sin b)$ will be positive when $a > b$. So the function is strictly increasing, hence injective.

Comment: Perfect, thanks!